# mainWindow.webContents.send() not received by ipcRenderer.on() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, desktop-application

The data that I want to display is in the form of a matrix of diseases, and when you click on the name of the matrix on the page of specialties, the page for displaying the diseases of this specialty opens.
index.js

```
 let maladie=document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
 maladie.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   let des= PathData.filter(function(ele){
      if(ele.name===el.innerText){
        return ele;
      }
    });
  let dataMaladie=des[0].Diseases;
  
  ipcRenderer.send('openmaladie-page',dataMaladie);
   e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

dataMaldie is an array with all the diseases of the specialty pressed on it and it displays correctly

Main.js . file

```
    ipcMain.on('openmaladie-page',function(e,data){

console.log(data);
   win.webContents.send("dataMaladie",data);
   
   
   creatWindow('maladie.html');
});
```

maladie.js

```
 const {ipcRenderer} =require('electron');

ipcRenderer.on('dataMaladie',function(e,data){
    
    console.log(data);
    let con=document.querySelector('#Diseases');
    for(let i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        let li=` <li class="col-3 patho ">
        <a href="#">
                <span class="ml-4 ">${data[i]}<span>
        </a>    
     </li>`;k`enter code here`
     con.append(li);
    }
   
});
```

Here after I receive the diseases in the matrix and inject them into the page and then display the page, there is no change in the html page of the diseases in addition to not printing anything in the console!!

Answer (score 0):

When calling `Element.append()` with string arguments, you can only insert plain text (not HTML elements) into the DOM. You'll have to create each element you want to insert using `document.createElement()` like so:

```js
// In your loop
let li = document.createElement ("li");
li.classList.add ("col-3", "patho");

let a = document.createElement ("a");
a.href = "#";

let span = document.createElement ("span");
span.classList.add ("ml-4");
span.innerText = data [i];

a.append (span);
li.append (a);
con.append (li);
```

You can assign any CSS classes you want using `Element.classList.add()`, by separating them into distinct strings.

One final remark: This code uses `Element.innerText` for the text in the span element, which means that any HTML contents of `data [i]` will be escaped, which is the right thing to do. By simply using string interpolation (like your original example) or using  `Element.innerHTML`, you're opening yourself (your app) up to user-defined DOM elements, which is discouraged since this could even include malicious JavaScript.

Comment: my problem in main.js win.WebContents.send not work

Comment: Is your `maladie.js` file linked from `maladie.html`, which you're opening **after** you send out the data for display? If so, you'll have to wait until the new `BrowserWindow` finished loading the HTML file. Also, if `creatWindow()` creates a new `BrowserWindow`, you won't reach the new window with the old `win` variable, possibly. But you haven't provided enough code to be sure.